# How can I change the speed of objects that are spawning in constantly in my game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm editing a Space Shooter game for class and I am trying to create a "Hard Mode" that speeds up the asteroids when the player presses the key "e". Currently with my code, pressing the key will speed up every asteroid that is currently on the screen but new asteroids spawned in are at regular speed. I have no idea how to fix and would like some suggestions in what to do. Here's my code:

```
 public float speed;

 private Rigidbody rb;

 Vector3 initialForwardVector;

 void Start()
 {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    initialForwardVector = transform.forward;
    rb.velocity = initialForwardVector * speed;
 }

 void Update()
 {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
    {
        rb.velocity = initialForwardVector * (2*speed);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest simplest solution:

```
public float speed;
public static float speedModifier = 1f;

private Rigidbody rb;

Vector3 initialForwardVector;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    initialForwardVector = transform.forward;
    rb.velocity = initialForwardVector * speed * speedModifier;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        speedModifier = 2f;
        rb.velocity = initialForwardVector * (speedModifier * speed);
    }
}
```

The speed modifer will apply to all new projectiles since the value is shared(static) between all instances of the class. For a more robust implementation i suggest adding an Initialize function that would set a local speed modifier for new asteroids.

Comment: I would suggest changing `rb.velocity = initialForwardVector * (speedModifier * speed);` to `rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * (speedModifier * speed);` to avoid all the asteroids changing direction suddenly...

Comment: Did not think about doing it that way, helps a lot! The only problem I'm seeing now is that the asteroids will sometimes change directions. I have them spawn with speed of -5 so they come down the screen so I would've thought the speed would stay negative but it seems to do it randomly, any idea what causes that?

EDIT: I fixed it. When I used `rb.velocity.normalized` like the comment, the direction sometimes messes up, but staying with my `initialForwardVector` made it work correctly. Thanks